# ADOでExcelファイルを使用した場合行削除が出来ない

Tags: c++, excel, mfc

C++からADOを使用してExcelファイルの行追加、検索、更新をしています。削除だけどうしてもできません。ADOでExcelファイルを指定した場合に、そのような制限はあるのでしょうか。「エラーを特定できません」となります。

```
CString strFile = _T("C:\\temp\\sample.xlsx");
CString s;
try
{
 CString strCon;
 strCon.Format( _T( "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=%s;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 xml" ) , strFile );
 con.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
 con->Open(_bstr_t(strCon), "", "", adConnectUnspecified);

 _RecordsetPtr rs;
 rs.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
 rs->CursorLocation = adUseClient;
 rs->Open(_variant_t( "SELECT * FROM [test$] WHERE [ID]='A1'" ), con.GetInterfacePtr(), adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText );

 if( !rs->GetadoEOF() )
 {
  rs->Delete(adAffectCurrent);
  rs->Close();
 }
}
catch(_com_error& e)
{
 s=e.ErrorMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

まず残念な話ですが、お使いのMicrosoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0ですが、配布はされていますがドキュメントは提供されていません。ですので詳しい挙動は不明としか言いようがありません。

これの前身？のMDACも既にドキュメントが散り散りになっています。とりあえず探し出せた範囲で[Microsoft Excel Driver Programming Considerations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-excel-driver-programming-considerations?view=sql-server-ver15) / [Read-Only Status (Excel Driver)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/read-only-status-excel-driver?view=sql-server-ver15)の中に

> It is possible to update values when using the Microsoft Excel driver, but a row cannot be deleted from a table based on a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet, so updates are not considered officially supported by the Microsoft Excel driver.

とありました。ACEも同じ仕様を引き継いでいて、行削除はサポートされていないのだと思われます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。やはりサポートされていない可能性が高いのですね。